# How to read a relative web path with Server.MapPath with space character in filename or path in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, server.mappath

What i get is

```
src = Request.QueryString["imgsrc"];//src = "images/file 15.jpeg";

System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath(src));
```

the second line returns System.IO.FileNotFoundException cause of the space in the path.

What should i do to encode or do something to read this kind of paths;

Comment: The space is not the problem. This works fine: `System.IO.File.Create("This is a file.jpg");`

Comment: Have you tried escaping quote marks around the path?

Comment: It may not be the space. It might be the path that is causing the problem. Is "images" folder at the same level as the executing file?

Comment: Yes it is at the same level. If i rename the file to file15.jpeg (path images/file15.jpg) then it works fine!

Comment: Sorry again, you are correct about spaces!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign Server.MapPath(src) to a temporary variable and then make sure that the path points to an existing file:

```
src = Request.QueryString["imgsrc"];//src = "images/file 15.jpeg";

string tempPath = Server.MapPath(src);

Debug.Assert(System.IO.File.Exists(tempPath);

System.Drawing.Image image = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(tempPath);
```

Comment: Guys, sorry my bad... I am dizzy after so much development and i forgot to rename the file in the filesystem expect from the database